# Client-side caching in JSF 1.2 / RichFaces 3.3.x

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I feel like this goes against the general paradigm of JSF but I thought I'd ask if it was possible.

I've got a `<rich:dataTable>` that is being rendered and for each iteration (row) a database lookup needs to take place to determine if the bean is editable. The trouble is I need to know if the bean is editable in a few locations, let this be *n*.

The problem then comes that I have to be *n* duplicate calls to the database.

This leads me to ask the question: is it possible to cache the result of the function call client-side for the duration of the iteration?

```
<rich:dataTable>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
    </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"/>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Editable"/>
    </f:facet>
        <!-- Cache the result of the 'isEditable' function call -->
        <h:outputText value="#{mylib:isEditable(bean) ? 'Yes' : 'No'}"/>
    </rich:column>
    <!-- More content which requires the editable value -->
</rich:dataTable>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If this value is available in bean object then this could apply:

```
    <h:outputText value="Yes" rendered="#{bean.isEditable=='YES'}" />
    <h:outputText value="No" rendered="#{bean.isEditable=='NO'}" />
```